# Disable row editing for only 1 cell in the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagrid, xceed

We have an Exceed DataGridControl. Row editing is enabled with a popup.
In the code behind of our WPF view we check for a specific column and add an inline editor.

When we click that specific cell the roweditor and cell editor are both enabled and this causes some inconsistent data.

I would like to disable row editing, but only when the cell is clicked with it's own inline editor.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by following code:

```
Public Sub PopupEditorMethod(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ExecuteCommandEventArgs(Of OurObject))
    Dim row = CType(e.OriginalSource, Xceed.Wpf.DataGrid.DataRow)
    row.EndEdit()

    'popup implementation
End Sub
```

We cancel the rowediting of our cell's parent row. This makes sure we don't have any inconsistent values.